# How to exclude a Dependency in Grails?

Tags: spring, grails, grails-2.0

In my BuildConfig.groovy I have

```
dependencies {

   compile 'org.package:abc:2.0.0'

}
```

abc has xyz as dependency. How can I exclude xyz?

I tried

```
dependencies {

   compile 'org.package:abc:2.0.0' {
     exclude: 'xyz'
   }

}
```

but this does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's **excludes**, not **exclude**...

```
 compile('org.package:abc:2.0.0') {
     excludes 'xyz'
  }
```